# how to change some of the rules in the database

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I need to add a rewrite rule for a WP page. I noticed that the rule is already part of the existing set, but apparently it is not correct.

With the hope some internal mechanism would have replaced the existing rule, I unsuccessfully hook the generate_rewrite_rules action:

```
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['faqs/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?faqs=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
```

What's the best way to proceed?

Comment: your question isn't entirely clear. if an incorrect rule was added, simply correcting the rule and then flushing rules will fix it. also you say you "need to add a rewrite rule for a WP page", but your rule is setting the query var `faqs`, which would seem to indicate you have a custom post type, not page. if that is the case, you don't need extra rules for pagination.

Comment: Hi @Milo thanks for your answer. I ultimately noticed that passing the right rule, this is overwritten. And I got the expected results, but not the pagination to work. I'm not sure I understand the last bit. Are you suggesting that a page already has a pagination mechanism and it should work without further efforts?